# PuLP variable definition from a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, pulp

I want to declare a set of variables with PuLP which contains all the possible combinations of the following lists:

```
month = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
manufacturer = ['China', 'Mexico', 'Taiwan']
demand = ['London', 'Paris', 'Milan']
```

Then, I will have a dictionary (for example) as follow:
`'1.China.London'`, `'1.China.Paris'`,...

I tried with the following code, but I don't know how to store all the combinations.

```
vlbs = {}
for key in month:
    for kay in manufacturer:
        for eyk in demand:
            vlbs = (str(key)+'.'+str(kay)+'.'+str(eyk))
```

First, I'm not getting properly the dictionary `vlbs`. And later on:

```
variables = {var: pl.LpVariable(var, lowBound = 0) for var in vlbs}
```

How can I solve it properly??

Comment: How would you like to store the combinations in a dataframe? With each row being a new combination?

Comment: I don't want to store it in a dataframe, but in a dictionary

Comment: Could you add an example desired output?

Comment: Not clear, why do you need dict for vars. The list should be fine for your case. But if you want dict you should do some thing like `vlbs[(str(key)+'.'+str(kay)+'.'+str(eyk))] = True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tuple as a dictionary key. I think this makes filtering/searching easier than doing a bunch of string concatenating and splitting.

```
months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
manufacturers = ['China', 'Mexico', 'Taiwan']
demands = ['London', 'Paris', 'Milan']

var_dict = {}

for month in months:
    for manufacturer in manufacturers:
        for demand in demands:
            combo = (month, manufacturer, demand)
            var_name = '.'.join([str(c) for c in combo])
            var_dict[combo] = LpVariable(var_name, lowBound=0) 

# add constraint for month 1
model += lpSum([k for k in var_dict if k[0] == 1]) <= 50
```